# Angular Modal dialog box - How to close the modal dialog when a Link(URL) is clicked in the modal dialog and take them to the link clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Modal dialog box -

I'm new to post a question here. Thanks for all your wonderful contribution answering other folks which I read and enlighten myself for the last few years.

I have a project (.net core with angular) where I want to open a URL in Angular material Modal Dialog (MatDialog) and when a link(URL) in the opened popup dialog is clicked, we would like to close the popup dialog (MatDialog) and take the user to the clicked URL ( Internal link though). Kind of like  facebook post click.

I was able to get the angular dialog box open up with URL content and can close the modal dialog (angular MatDialog). But when a link is clicked within modal popup dialog, it opens the content inside the modal dialog itself. What we like is to close the Modal dialog and take the user to the Clicked URL in a new page ( Not another window or tab but in the same tab).

If it can be achieved in any other way, please let me know.

If I'm not clear, please ask or let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a stack blitz in order to edit that? Or I can post an answer not totally releated to a mat dialog, but the logic is the same

Comment: Go through https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview use `afterClosed` method

Comment: Vikas, I'm using afterClosed to close the dialog. The question is different. User clicks a link on the modal dialog and when that happens, we need to close the dialog and at the mean time capture the link clicked by the user and redirect/route them to that new page

Jacopo, Please post your way of doing it and I'll see if i can add this code to stack blitz. Never used that myself but have seen other's sample many a time . :-) 

Thank you both

Comment: A code sample would be helpful. What is an "Internal link"? Is it an application route? Or a static link to another page? What is the "link" that is being clicked? An anchor tag? Or a button, or ...?

Comment: HI Tranter, Yes Static link to an another page within the website( not external URL). It is an anchor tag

Here is the sample. Stackblictz is not opening the URL in the modal dialog's Iframe. Locally in my .net core with angular app, it does open and in that page, they could be zero to any number of anchor tags and when we click on it, the goal is to close the modal dialog,  capture that clicked link/href (anchor tag href value) and direct the user to that page.
 , 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jturd

Comment: @Robert you can pass the link clicked by the user to the component hosting your model in `afterClosed` method and then navigate to it? what's the challenge you are facing with that?

Comment: @Vikas,  Do you have a sample or update this one to show that? Thanks 

https://angular-rp1elw.stackblitz.io